# Reverse a list of list in F#

Tags: list, f#

I want to reverse a function called revLists that takes a list of lists and reverses all the sub-lists.

Any suggestion will help.

This is my idea:

```
let revLists[[]] = List.map (fun [[]] -> List.rev);;
revLists[[1;2;3],[4;5]];;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
let lists = [[1;2;3];[4;5]]
let reverseLists list = list |> List.map List.rev

> reverseLists lists;;         
val it : int list list = [[3; 2; 1]; [5; 4]]
```

Comment: thanks, what the |> for, return statement like ->? @Foole

Comment: @MarkDwayne That is the forward pipe operator.  See: http://www.kevinberridge.com/2012/12/neat-f-pipe-forward.html

Comment: thanks again if I want to interleave 2 lists, is there a way that I can accomplish that without using list.zip?                                                                   > interleave ([1;2;3],[4;5;6]);; should produce [1;4;2;5;3;6] @Foole

Comment: I have this but it is giving errors:                                                                           let interleave a b = List.filter List.head a List.head b a b;;                                   These are preparation f# questions for tests, thanks. @Foole

Comment: @MarkDwayne You should post this as a new question

Comment: yes but stackoverflow doesn't let me, it says that I have asked 6 questions already in the past month and have not been well received by the community @Foole

Comment: @MarkDwayne It is really not good. But you can get help in the [F# chat room on SO](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f) and I strongly recommend joining to the [F# Slack](http://fsharp.org/guides/slack/)